# HTTParty get request ignores query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I'm trying to make a GET request with a quersytring, however, HTTParty is ignoring my params. For example, I'm doing something like this:

```
headers = {"User-Agent"=>"whatever", "Authorization"=>"whatever"} 
options = {"sport" => "mlb" }
HTTParty.get("https://www.erikberg.com/events.json", query: options, headers: headers)
```

The response should be empty since yesterday there wasn't any MLB game going on. I checked with curl and worked properly. However, when I use this gem I'm getting NBA games (ignoring the param sport). I asked to the owner of the API and he told me I'm getting two redirects (302, 301).

Any clue of what is failing here? Is my request really using https?

Best regards!

Comment: httparty follows redirects automatically to the resource. You need to use the block method to check the headers for the response and see what you actually get back instead. If it's a redirect, react on it that you didn't find anything and see what it actually redirects you to.

Comment: I have just find out the domain name was incorrect (erikberg.com is the correct one), so there was the error.